# Changed Jenkins_home to new location

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins running in Docker container and I'm mounting `/opt/software/jenkins` into.

I installed Jenkins on server, because I'm trying to shutdown Jenkins that is running in Container.

For Testing purpose I changed JENKINS_HOME=`/opt/software/jenkins` in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and I started Jenkins, so it is not coming up. Do I have to change anything else? In order just to use existing `/opt/software/jenkins` path?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? You have a docker container and the host operating system. Do you have Jenkins installed twice (once in the container and once on the host)? Did you change /etc/sysconfig/jenkins in your host or in your container? Why not stop Jenkins in the container with `docker stop`?

Comment: Yes I have installed Jenkins twice(one in container and one on the host.I changed /etc/sysconfig/jenkins file on host to use JENKINS_HOME=/opt/software/jenkins path,I'm mounting that path to a container currently.. I can't stop Jenkins Container until Jenkins that installed on host in not fully functional.. The whole point is that I just want to have Jenkins running on a host with everything that Jenkins container has..

Comment: Ah! So you're using bind mounts to mount your data directory from your container to your host? Why not simply copy the data from your bind point to the `JENKINS_HOME` for your host? You're _very_ likely to cause problems if you have two instances of Jenkins running off the same `JENKINS_HOME` at one time.

Comment: I get that, but the point is as soon as Jenkins on a host will come up, Jenkins in container will go down. But I'm mounting /opt/software/jenkins path.. Jenkins is running(exited) status..Just changing home_work should work.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's nothing that would cause Jenkins in your container to shut down after coming up on your host unless you've accounted for that somehow. In any case, if you want to proceed down this path, check your syslog (usually `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`) to see what Jenkins is complaining about when it tries to come up.

Comment: I meant that I will bring Jenkins container down! Ok I will check that thank you